# ng-options creates new instance of model instead of getting one from the datasource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does `ng-options` clone objects and if that is the case is there some way to stop it?

in the following code:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
  <select ng-options="item as item.text for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="item">
      <option value="">select something else</option>
    </select>
  <button ng-click="test()">
      test
    </button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Main', function($scope) {
    const Test = function(id, text) {
      this.id = id;
      this.text = text;
    }
    $scope.items = [new Test('1', 'test1'), new Test('2', 'test2')];
    $scope.item = null;
    $scope.test = function() {
      if (!$scope.items.includes($scope.item) && $scope.item !== null) {
        alert("Items should contain item?")
        debugger;
      }
    }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0a918n4/

Select a item in the drop down an click the button.
The `alert` should not happen, but for some reason the `$scope.item` variable seems to be a clone and not the exact same reference? (Does `ng-options` + `track by` some how clone the object and create a new instance?)

If you select the first item and use a debugger and write `$scope.items[0] === $scope.item` it results in false?

Comment: it is working as expected , i think you should not use (not operator) !$scope.items.includes($scope.item) which is true because $scope is not in $scope.items and it is not null , so you will get alert

Comment: created codepen , removing not operator - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MLQKmZ

Comment: @naga if I remove the ! It would not check if the item is the same..., but after analysing the source code of angularjs I found a angular.copy or clone that only runs when track by is used. I don't get why track by should cause a clone to be created.

Comment: Track by is making a copy of the value to your ngModel

Comment: @aseferov I'm so confused by that behavior. I'm trying to use track by to stop it from adding the hash code and instead use the ID field I provided.

Comment: Why you need reference same object ? You can check it include items by another way . Here is [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15980) on github.

Comment: @aseferov it's not like I don't know how to solve this issue, just use some and the ID field, it's just bugging me that it creates a new instance when I didn't tell it to.

Comment: @aseferov please post a answer that says it works as intended and add a link to the issue.